# Drawing mountains using 1px swing rectangles

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm trying to draw mountains background using 1-width rectangles (something like integrals). I randomize the first point to the very left of the screen, randomize binary number and draw the first rectangle.

If binary number is 0, the next rectangle will be 1px lower. Else higher. And so on in the for loop.

There's a 95% chance that in the next loop the direction won't change and it will keep going higher/lower. And 5% chance the direction will change. For this I'm using randomized number from 1 to 1000.

```
public Landscape(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        Random rand = new Random();
        int first = rand.nextInt((800 - 200) + 1) + 200;
        g2d.fillRect(0, 800 - first, 1, first);

        int d = first % 2;

        for(int i = 1; i <= 800; i++) {
            int choose = rand.nextInt((1000 - 1) + 1) + 1;

            if(choose > 950) {
                d = -(d);
            }

            if(d == -1) {
                first += 1;                
            } else {
                first -= 1;
            }

            g2d.fillRect(i, 800 - first, 1, first);
        }
    }
```

[image]

That's the effect I get in like half cases. Sometimes however I get something like this:

[image]

How is this possible? What's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
int d = first % 2;
```

d is either 1 or 0. If d is assigned 0, then `if(d == -1) {` is always false, and thus your graph will go monotonically downwards.

You are looking for a two state solution to decide whether the mountain goes up or down, so use a boolean. Perhaps something like:

```
boolean direction = rand.nextBoolean();

// 1 in 20 chance, same as 5 in 100, same as 50 in 1000 chance
if (rand.nextInt(20) == 0) { 
   direction = !direction;
}

if (direction) {
   // ... 
} else {
   // ...
}
```

Myself, I'd look into using fractals.